# Finding extremum value of a symmetric expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a+b+c+d=k$ how to find the extremum value of any symmetric expression in a,b,c,d?For example say $abc+bcd+cda+dab$.

I've noticed that it usually occurs when a=b=c=d.Why does this happen?

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$  are nonnegative then maximum of your symmetric expression is reached when $a=b=c=d$ but minnimum when at least two of the variables are $0$

Comment: @Booldy i asked why..

Comment: here is why https://www.google.ba/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwi9trTlwrXHAhXCzxQKHR3_ACo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMaclaurin%27s_inequality&ei=zKjUVb2gKcKfU53-g9AC&usg=AFQjCNGYWK54JllX3IbR8e3B4rBFmbWvrQ&sig2=JcHzuXsyf67SxZdw9klXvw

Comment: i just wanted to point that it is not true always.If $a,b,c,d$ can be negative then extremas aer usualy reached at another point

Answer (score 0):

This is due to symmetry of $a,b,c,d$ i.e. any two can be interchanged without making any change to these expressions.